# windows batch file encrypted text not print

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have property file config.proprties and trying to grab encrypted text but batch is skipping special character like "=". How do I achieve this?

config.properties

```
dev_encrypted_password=pxthbdUD2xm=
```

test.bat

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%i IN ('findstr /i %env_name%_encrypted_password %prop_file%') DO ECHO %%i
```

so its on print "pxthbdUD2xm" and skip the "=" sign.
Any advice would greatly appreciated it.

Comment: The equals symbol is your delimiter so it is going to get rid of the equals symbol in all of your data.  To get around that use: `"tokens=1* delims=="` and then echo the FOR variable `%%j`.

Comment: Based upon the advice in the comment above: `@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%G In ('%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /BIL "%env_name%_encrypted_password=" "%prop_file%" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %%H`.

Comment: Thanks it is working. Greatly appreiated